# Using push_front in a for loop doesn't permanently add a member to the list

Tags: c++, list, loops, constructor, destructor

I am trying to use the push_front() function on a list of a class I created. I have it in a for loop but whenever the loop inserts the new member into the list, it is automatically destroyed right after, I'm assuming because it is out of scope. My question is how do I add these items permanently.

Example:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(){std::cout << "creation" << std::endl;}
    ~foo(){std::cout << "destruction" << std::endl;}
    bool create() {return true;}
};

int main()
{
    std::list<foo> foolist(4);
    for (std::list<foo>::iterator i=foolist.begin(); i!=foolist.end(); i++)
    {
        foolist.push_front(foo());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
creation
creation
creation
creation
creation
destruction
creation
destruction
creation
destruction
creation
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
```

When this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
creation
creation
creation
creation
creation
creation
creation
creation
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
destruction
```

Comment: Why does the title refer to an `if` statement when there is no `if` in the code?  Moreover, why are you iterating over the list while simultaneously calling `push_front` on it?

Comment: You are adding them. The temporaries created in the intermediate add are what is being destroyed. Change that to `foolist.emplace_front();` (no content in the parens). Note you will need a C++11 toolchain for this to work.

Comment: @jwodder, Sorry about that, this is just an example, not the actual thing I'm working on; in my project, I have an if statement in the for loop that determines creation, but I realized in making this example it doesn't change anything (that the for loop is the one actually responsible.)

Comment: @WhozCraig, I tried doing what you suggested, but I get the same output? How can I make sure I have the c++11 toolchain?

Comment: Your title is highly confusing.

Comment: @user3850982 "I get the same output" - Um [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/G8AKqK). It is *not* the same output.

Comment: @WhozCraig How can I make my IDE do the same? I'm running CodeBlocks and it's outputting the same thing as with push_front.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me your calling `emplace_front()` like this: `emplace_front(foo(args...))`. Don't. Call it like this: `emplace_front(args...)`. If `args...` is nothing, then call it like this: `emplace_front()` (like I showed in my first comment). Regarding your IDE, make sure `-std=c++11` is passed as a config switch during compile and link.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hi craig, your advice worked!! Thank you very much. I am new to stackoverflow, don't know how to thank people if such a feature exists, but many thanks to you regardless :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's walk through this program one line at a time.

```
std::list<foo> foolist(4);
```

Default constructor for `foo` called 4 times.

```
foolist.push_front(foo());
```

This statement runs 4 times. Each time, a `foo` is default constructed. `push_front` calls the implicitly defined move constructor in order to move this temporary `foo` object into the list. (Or the copy constructor if you're still in C++03 mode.) You don't see anything printed, because it's not the default constructor. At the end of each iteration, the temporary `foo` is destroyed.

```
    return 0;
}
```

The list now contains 8 `foo`s, so the destructor is called 8 times.

Comment: If this is a temporary foo being created and destroyed, how do I instead create an entirely new foo directly into the list? I am trying to create a program that outputs based on class member's creation and destruction ("Birth" and "Death" of bunnies.. haha)

Comment: @user3850982 Use `foolist.emplace_front()`, as suggested in the question comments.

Comment: Thank you Brian. My emplace_front() doesn't seem to work correctly, as I get the same output as when I use push_front(). What should I do with my IDE to get it to work properly?

Comment: @user3850982 Looks like your problem is solved in the question comments.

Comment: Yeah, both of these answers deserve upticks. They're both correct. there ya go!

Comment: Thanks everyone. stackoverflow is a great community!! I never expected such speedy responses. Was skeptical about learning more outside of classtime, but this is great!

Comment: @user3850982 Stack Overflow is very good at answering questions when questions are asked properly. Just keep that in mind and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 2):

The extra "creation" and "destruction" are due to the temp variables you're creating by calling

```
foo()
```

Those temp variables get copied into brand new items in the list which ALSO get created when push_front gets called and destroyed when the list falls out of scope